# Most visited vertex in a random walk with place dependent drift

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walks

Consider the following Markov chain on $\mathbb{Z}$:
$$
P(x,x+1)=1-P(x,x-1)=\frac{1}{2}+e^{-|x|}\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{x\neq 0\}}
$$

Do there exist constants $c,C>0$ such that 
$$
c\cdot P^t(z,z) \leq P^t(0,0)\leq C\cdot P^t(z,z)
$$

for all $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $t\in\mathbb{N}$?

$$
%c\cdot \Pr[X_{2t}=z|X_0=z]\leq \Pr[X_{2t}=0|X_0=0]\leq C\cdot %\Pr[X_{2t}=z|X_0=z]
%$$
$$
%\Pr[X_{t+1}=x+1|X_t=x]=1-\Pr[X_{t+1}=x-1|X_t=x]=\frac{1}{2}+e^{-|x|}\cdot %\mathbf{1}_{\{x\neq 0\}}
%$$